# make top image overflow in showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am using showModalBottomSheet to show sheet widget.
There i want half image to overflow the sheet and other half inside the sheet.

Here in my code i am trying to overflow the red container in sheet.
Could you please recommend me some approach ?

Expected

[image]

Actual

[image]

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20))),
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              FractionallySizedBox(
                heightFactor: 0.6,
                child:
                    PersonProfile(person),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: -50,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
        isScrollControlled: true,
      );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there!

Just add clip behaviour in your stack.

```
Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: -50,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Output:

[image]

Use `Positioned` and `Clip.none` inside the `Stack` to get the desired behaviour.

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 40,
              top: -40,
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use   `transform: Matrix4.translationValues(), and stack`

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      // using a scaffold helps to more easily position the FAB
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Stack(
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: double.maxFinite,
                                height: 200,
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 81, 168, 128),
                                  child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          'Pressana',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 36,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "You",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                                        )
                                      ]),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                                      0.0, -75, 0.0), // translate up by 30
                                  child: Icon(Icons.circle,
                                      size: 150, color: Colors.indigoAccent)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],

                     
                      );
                    })
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/inbz4.png